# Vue optionMergeStrategies Methods has no access to 'this' keyword

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to build a plugin for Vue.
My plugin has a custom method caller `customMethod` for every component, I want it to run on after the page is mounted/created.
In a simple way, this is working as I want but I am having trouble accessing `this` inside customMethod.

It logs 'undefined'  when I am trying to `console.log(this)`.

so how can I access `this` inside my `customMethod` ?

```js
var defaultParms = Object.freeze({
 start   : function(){},
 leave   : function(){},
});



const myPlugin = {
    
    install(Vue, options = []) {
        var ref = Vue.util;
        var extend = ref.extend;

        var assets = Object.create(null);
        extend(assets, defaultParms);
        Vue.options.customMethod = assets;

        
        
        // set option merge strategy
        var strats = Vue.config.optionMergeStrategies;
        if (strats) {
            strats.customMethod = (parent, child, vm)=>{
                
                if (!child) return parent;
                if (!parent) return child;

                var ret = Object.create(null);
                extend(ret, parent);

                for (var key in child) {
                    ret[key] = child[key];
                }
                return ret
            };
        }


        Vue.mixin({
            customMethod:{
                start: function(){
                  console.log('hi') // log 'hi'
                  console.log(this.$appName)  // log 'undefined'
                }
            },
            created: function () {
                if(this.$options.customMethod){
                    this.$options.customMethod.start && this.$options.customMethod.start();
                }
            }
        });


        Vue.prototype.$appName = 'vikash';
    }

}


Vue.use(myPlugin)
new Vue().$mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is part of how the context `this` works in JS. You need to set it with `bind`, `call` or `apply`:

```js
this.$options.customMethod.start.call(this)
```